# Using dendrogram in R (or other methods) how can I produce a plot of individuals' ID with same number

Tags: r, dendrogram

I would like to visualize individuals with the same numbers using a dendrogram .

```
dat <- read.table(text="Id  Resistance.Number    
A   0405611540527610     
B   6607734653564010  
C   0405611540527610 
D   030402066763231     
E   0405611540527610  
F   4417610555422211
G   0043551103500252     
H   1043453103501272    
I   030402066763231", header=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a dendrogram based on string similarities using `stringsimmatrix` from the `stringdist` package. After that make sure your matrix has the right column and row names to convert it to a `dist` object which can be used to create a dendogram like this:

```r
library(stringdist)

# Similarities
similarities <- stringsimmatrix(dat$Resistance.Number)
colnames(similarities) <- dat$Id
rownames(similarities) <- dat$Id

# Plot
d <- dist(similarities)
d <- hclust(d)
dend <- as.dendrogram(d)
plot(dend)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

**Data:**

I created this data to make sure the Numbers were as character like this:

```
dat <- data.frame(Id = LETTERS[1:9],
                  Resistance.Number = c("0405611540527610", "6607734653564010", "0405611540527610", "030402066763231", "0405611540527610",
                                        "4417610555422211", "0043551103500252", "1043453103501272", "030402066763231"))
```

Comment: How can I transform Resistance.Number if I have a huge dataset?

Comment: Hi @YASIRAA, What do you actually mean by transform?

Comment: To make them as character like

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?